# How to chekbox Checked dynamically in custom adapter

Tags: android

I am trying to set all checkbox to set true when i click selectall button

private void selectall(){
        selectall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


           //CheckBox checkBox= SelectsongAdapter.checkBox;
            if (state == deslected) {

              // checkBox.setChecked(true);
                //if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                   SelectsongAdapter.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                        longArrayList.add(arrayList.get(i).getId());
                        //checkBox.setChecked(false);
                        SelectsongAdapter.checkBox.setChecked(true);
                        selectall.setText("Deselect");
                        state=selected;

                    //}
                    counttxt.setText(String.valueOf(longArrayList.size()));
                }
            }
            else if(state == selected){
               // SelectsongAdapter.checkBox.setChecked(false);
                selectall.setText("SelectAll");
                //checkBox.setChecked(false);
                counttxt.setText(String.valueOf(0));
                longArrayList.clear();
                state=deslected;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your adapter code ?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Initialize your Custom Adapter say `myAdapter`

```
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(NotificatioTest.this,mArrayListSource);
```

Set Adapter to ListView `mListView`

```
mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

**Step 2**

For Select all CheckBox view add `setOnCheckedChangeListener` listener as:

```
chkBoxSelectAll.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        mArrayListSource.clear();
        for(int i=0; i < YourSongsArrayList.size(); i++){
            Module mModule = new Module();
            mModule.isChecked = isChecked;
            mModule.mText = "" + isChecked;
            mArrayListSource.add(mModule);
        }
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Module :

```
class Module {
    public boolean isChecked = false;
    public String mSongName = "";
}
```